# How do I change www-data home directory from /var/www to /home/www-data?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, home-directory, www-data

I'm setting up a private Ubuntu web server. In my company I'm used to a deployment where the home folder of www-data is in /home/www-data, but on my plain Ubuntu installation it is in /var/www.

Now how can I change this? With `usermod -d`? And is this a good idea anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is:

`usermod -d /home/www-data www-data`

But keep in mind you are changing the Ubuntu apache defaults and maybe breaking some things. Check the Ubuntu docs for details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html).

Answer (score 0):

- Are you using Apache web server?
- You can still continue with the same default Document Root Directory "/var/www/html" but if you wish to
  change your document root directory, you can make the changes in your web server configuration file which
  you can find
  in "/etc/apache2/" (In case of ubuntu serve, please refer to this path for web server configuration file)
- You should go through the Ubuntu server giude, It will probably answer your questions on getting your web server setup

  https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/httpd.html

Comment: Why are you linking to 8.04's server guide? We're on 12.10 now...  and 13.04 has the same doc. https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/httpd.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will not use apache, I have a Django application server setup, so I think I can change the home folder of www-data with `usermod -d /home/www-data www-data` and leave the apache configuration as it is. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the dir contents moved, add the -m option to usermod:

```
usermod -m -d /home/www-data www-data
```